# Angular 5 Table Not Updating

Tags: angular, ngfor

I have a table that I use to display Place Details that I am get from the Angular Maps.

The code in component.ts is

```
ngOnInit()
  {
    this.mapsAPILoader.load().then(() =>
    {
      this.placesService = new google.maps.places.PlacesService(document.createElement('div'));

      this.placesService.getDetails(
      { placeId: this.placeID }, (pR, s) =>
      {
        if(s === 'OK')
        {
          this.infoResults = this.makeInfoArray(pR);
        }
      });
    });
  }

  makeInfoArray(pR)
  {
    let infoResults = [];
    if (pR.formatted_address)
    {
      infoResults.push({"field": "A", "value": pR.formatted_address});
    }

    return (infoResults);
  }
```

The table is made like this

```
<table class="table">
  <tr *ngFor="let info of infoResults">
    <th scope="row">{{ info.field }}</th>
    <td>{{ info.value }}</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

The problem is that when the variable infoResults is updated, with the data asynchronously returned by Angular Maps, the table data does not update.

What can be done in this case ?

Comment: All we can say is: fix your code, because you didn't post it.

Comment: Can you try using a ngIf like this: `<table class="table" *ngIf="infoResults"> `?

Comment: Agree with @JBNizet. Please let us see the code in your component.

Comment: post also the code how you are updating the infoResults

Comment: @JBNizet  code posted

Comment: @CassianoMontanari tried that didn't work either

Comment: 1: why do you use an array and a ngFor to only store a single element? 2. Have you debugged your code? Are you sure it really initializes infoResults?  Or just simply added console.log() here and there to be sure the code is executed as you think it is, and the variables contain what you think theu contain?

Comment: @JBNizet here i have shown only a single element but i have a few more as well, and i have also checked using console.log

Comment: @JBNizet any solution for this ?

Comment: What's the output if you add `console.log(this.infoResults)` after `this.infoResults = this.makeInfoArray(pR);`? Can you post a complete minimal example as a stackblitz?

Comment: @JBNizet console.log shows what I push, but somehow it does not shown in the html. 
Strangely, when i click on anything inside that component the data shows up in html.